# Keith-Wood datepicker onclick (doesn't work on first click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, datepicker

In a GWT application i'm trying to use  this component:

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

In their page they explain that we need to use the following jquery function to use it:

```
$(function() {
$('#popupDatepicker').datepick();
});

<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker">
```

Due to requirements aplication i can´t use it like described so i use the onClick event like this:

```
<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker" 
       onClick="$('#popupDatepicker').datepick();">
```

In this way, the component is loaded but only on the second click (my first click doesn't do anying)

Has anyone had this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can't you just put a `<script>` block after the `<input>` where you perform the initialization?  (What "requirement" would possibly prevent you from doing the initialization as recommended, anyway?)

Comment: The result of putting the <script> block after the <input> is the same.. 

My "requirement" is: i must have the possibility of having several datepicker component (in my application i'm using always the same HTML template). 

I'm having problem in passing a param to the $(function() {
$('#popupDatepicker').datepick();
});

I've tried to do something like this but it doesn't work (i don't have knowledge on jQuery :/ )


$(function test(param) {
$('#param').datepick();
});

Comment: Then give your `<input>` elements a class, like "datepick", and then you can do `$(function() { $('.datepick').datepick(); });` That will initialize all such `<input>` elements on the page.

Comment: This is the way that the show in the site.. but you can't have 2 input with the same id... that why i'm using onClick function to workaround this situation...

Comment: I said **class** not id.  You can definitely use a class selector, or at least you can if the datepicker plugin is not broken.  That's how jQuery works.

Comment: Now i understand and it worked :) Perfect. Thanks a lot. Could you answer the question officially, i want to accept your answer and you deserve it :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16200/discussion-between-user1106986-and-pointy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use any selector string to initialize date picker elements on the page. Thus, you could give your `<input>` elements a class:

```
 <input class='datepick' name='whatever'>
```

and then initialize all of them  with:

```
 $(function() {
   $('.datepick').datepick();
 });
```